# How to mint a token on Cardano?

Tags: nft, mint

I need help on how can I mint a token on the cardano blockchain for example an image as an NFT.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to mint an NFT IMG token on Cardano is by using https://www.nft-maker.io/. If you want to make it yourself then https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/native-tokens/getting-started-with-native-tokens.html is a good starting point.

Comment: This is also a very interesting guide https://bikemonkey.tech/minting-an-nft-on-cardano-with-daedalus-and-macos/

Answer (score 2):

The documentation has been updated and is now at: https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/learn

Comment: Welcome to our community! This is an unusually short answer. Pehaps you can highlight/summarize what the documentation says about how to mint a coin.